# Oauth 2: Is access_token a unique key for User?

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

After a user [connects with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), Facebook responds with an `access_token`.

Can I assume this `access_token` will always stay the same and is unique for every user?

If so, then I can use it to find the user in my database, and if not found, create a new user.

If not, is there a way to ask Facebook to also send you back `user_id` (with the `access_token`) right after connecting so that I don't have to make another request to `/me?fields=id` for it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959623/is-an-oauth-2-0-token-forever-unique-to-the-provider

Answer (score 5):

You should use their `id` as a unique identifier. The `access_token` is unique, but you'll get a new one every time you request one.

Comment: ok -> but what exactly is 'their id'? AFAIK oauth doesn't have anything similar to openid's unique id... From what can see oauth doens't have unique provider ids.

Comment: @RyanSpeets Can you provide links to sources backing up this answer?  Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth access_token can be duplicated during 2+ token issuers.
It is unique only in the token issuer (facebook.com in this case).
Since facebook token is enough long, token duplicates will rarely happen though.