# Is an OAuth 2.0 token forever unique to the provider?

Tags: unique, oauth-2.0, token, provider

When an OAuth 2.0 provider issues a token, is that token value forever unique to the provider?  Or is it possible that sometime in the future, presumably after the token expires, another token, potentially for a different user, could be issued with the same value?  In searching I found much information about tokens expiring, but no details about if that token value could potentially be re-used in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the core OAuth 2 spec that guarantees this. It is implementation specific if there is a chance of collision or not. You should find out from your OAuth AS provider what the likelihood is. But agreed with Artem - this sounds odd if you are trying to uniquely identify users based on what is suppose to be just an API (access) token.

Comment: @Duke Do you mind sharing what method you *did* end up using to uniquely identify your users?  I am trying to figure out the same thing as you did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like UUID - it's time dependent and unique - so you should NOT make them reusable. Taking in account that you'll generate tokens in different instants of time - they all will be different.

Comment: I understand that it's possible to always issue unique tokens as a provider, but I'm asking the question as a consumer.  I'd like to know if I can depend on new tokens from the same provider always being unique.  Is there a rule in the spec about this or is it up to the provider?

Comment: I'd like to use the token as a unique identifier for the user, long after it expires.  But of course this depends on the token being forever unique.  It would be a problem if a different user could receive the same token in the future and then impersonate another user.

Comment: You make use of token in a way contrary to what it is supposed to be used. What makes you to take this approach?